# Adapting a large crock pot recipe to a smaller crock pot

Tags: slow-cooking, crockpot

**I've found similar questions, but they have all be very generic. I'm curious about a specific recipe**, http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/sandra-lee/smothered-meatloaf-recipe.html

It calls for a 5-qt slow cooker, but mine is 2.5 quarts. I want to know if
1.) can I just half the ingredients?
2.) do I also need to half the cooking time?

Comment: The old question has an answer which says that scaling works for all recipes besides jellies. So I don't see a point in making a question for a specific recipe, as it is clearly covered in the existing question and answer.

Comment: I still maintain that the answer to the linked question is to generic, and leaves too much up in the air "If you are doing this, then maybe, but if you are doing that, then maybe not" but whatever... I cut back the cooking time per the other post, got food poisoning due to undercooked meat, and died.

Comment: Also, the first comment on the linked post: "That will depend on the total volume of the ingredients, and the type of ingredients. ... Can you tell us more about the recipe?" - Based on that, I made a post which told more about the recipe.

Comment: @chasepeeler Looking at that recipe, the general answer is fine. Your main thing in scaling the recipe will be to make it fit. If you're at all concerned that something hasn't fully cooked, use a thermometer to check.

Comment: @chasepeeler The concerns in the comment are practical: if you're making something prone to boiling over (you aren't), be careful. The other answer says that the only cases you might not just scale are jelly, or generally, things using pectin to set (you aren't doing that), and that you might have to reduce the cooking time (which applies to you). Beyond that, it doesn't really depend on the recipe, so it certainly seems like the other question and answer should suffice. Is there anything you're trying to ask that didn't get answered?

Comment: As someone without much experience with using a slow cooker, everything that may be obvious to you, isn't to me. The answer provided by @Jefromi, though, does answer my question. Thank you.

Comment: And since my comment only summarized what was on the other question and answer, this is indeed a duplicate.